# How do i Upgrade from Qt5 to Qt5.4 on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmake, qt5

My OS is Kubuntu 14.04.

I installed Qt5 via `apt-get install libqt5-dev`

How can i upgrade my Qt to the new Version of Qt(5.4)? I could install it manually but then the files in `usr/include` etc. are not updated and CMake is always searching there first, therefore not the newest Version will be picked. Is there a way to do something like `make install` to upgrade the existing Qt Version that will be used as default?

Comment: If you add the 5.4's bin folder (where qmake is) to the PATH before /usr/bin, it should pick up 5.4, not the one in /usr.

Comment: This is a probably a better question for SO's sister site, [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: @MrEricSir: Not Ubuntu-specific though, applies to any system where a qmake is in the user's default PATH.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Sure, but the way you install packages on Ubuntu is Ubuntu specific, and there are Qt PPAs available.  And this question has come up several times on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590162/qt-5-4-supported-so-files-come-with-default-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-or-not/590189#590189

Comment: I have downloaded Qt 5.4 community from Qt.io and installed by running the installer, it works just fine. My suggestion is that you apt-get remove libqt5-dev and install the new version from the website